# IntlDateFormatter::format(): datefmt_format: takes either an array or an integer timestamp value or a DateTime object (SonataSanBox)

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.3, intl

I have installed `SonataAdmin Bundle`. All is working fine but, when I add any user from dashboard, it throws a warning:

> Warning: IntlDateFormatter::format(): datefmt_format: takes either an array or an integer timestamp value or a DateTime object in C:\wamp\www\sonata-sandbox\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType.php on line 260

Comment: Can you report the issue with more extra information on the Github page https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues?state=open ? Thanks

Comment: Are you running wamp 64-bit or 32-bit? You should try the 64-bit version. According to this issue that was the solution: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1604

Answer (score 0):

when you persist user->dateRelatedProperty are you sure your attempting to set a " DateTime object, an IntlCalendar object, a numeric type representing a (possibly fractional) number of seconds since epoch or an array in the format output by localtime(). " --from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php) I have a feeling this is a case of having an incorrect type or format.